# Radio button does not return selected value

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am using radio button list control in asp.net. 
i m trying to get selected value on button click Event
but,i m getting `Empty string`  and i want it without javascript.

How can i do this?

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" EnableViewState="true" runat="server" 
    Width="287px">
<asp:ListItem Value="Single" runat="server" Text="Single"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="Jointly" runat="server" Text="Married Filing Jointly/Widower"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="Separately" runat="server" Text="Married Filing Separately"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="Household" runat="server" Text="Head Of Household "></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

C# code

```
protected void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string selectedValue = RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code you have so far?

Comment: Are you (re-)setting the selection in Page.Load?

Comment: this is doing exactly what it should for me .. can you show your page_load method?

Comment: no onPageload Event i m Doing nothing with Radiobuttonlist

Comment: @rohanpanchal please see my updated answer below you don't have any item selected as default, hence you get empty string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you bind your RadioButtonList, you can place your code in `! IsPostback` , in order to don't `erase` your `selected value, when you post your control (click event).

Page_Load :

```
if(! isPostBack)
{
   //Bind your radioButtonList

}`
```

Nota : You persist your datas with `ViewState`

Answer (score 0):

**Remarks from MSDN for RadioButttonList SelectedValue**

> This property returns the Value property of the selected ListItem. The
>   SelectedValue property is commonly used to determine the value of the
>   selected item in the list control. If multiple items are selected, the
>   value of the selected item with the lowest index is returned. *If no
>   item is selected, an empty string ("") is returned.*

So suggest #1 is that you atleast make on the item as default selection by using the attribute Selected="true"

Suggestion #2 will be (just a opinion) for the sake of readability use SelectedItem.Value

```
protected void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string selectedValue = RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first check your postback event in your page_load..then you can use **RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue**

Answer (score 0):

Or You could use :--

```
string selectedValue = RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue.ToString();
```